# How-to customize NERDTree behavior

Tags: vim, customization, nerdtree

I recently added NERDTree and NERDTreeTabs to my vim configuration and I'm quite happy about it.

However, I wanted to configure it a bit further and have the following behavior:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>:

- If inside the NERDTree, do nothing.
- If inside the edited file, go to the opened NERDTree, opening one first if none is present. I guess `NERDTreeTabsToggle` should be used, but to use it, I must be able to detect if a NERDTree is already open, not to close it by "toggling" it.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>:

- If inside the NERDTree, go back to the edited file without closing NERDTree. (Just like what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>Right</kbd> would do.)
- If inside the edited file, hide/close the NERDTree.

However, my Vim script skills are way to low for me to get any satisfying result. For instance, I can't figure out how to check what the current active window is or how to write the appropriate conditional statements.

Can someone help me with that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If finally found a way.

I edited the `nerdtree_plugin/vim-nerdtree-tabs.vim` file, adding these functions:

```
" === Stepped Open/Close functions ===
" focus the NERDTree view, creating one first if none is present
fun! s:NERDTreeSteppedOpen()
  if !s:IsCurrentWindowNERDTree()
    if s:IsNERDTreeOpenInCurrentTab()
      call s:NERDTreeFocus()
    else
      call s:NERDTreeMirrorOrCreate()
    endif
  endif
endfun

" unfocus the NERDTree view or closes it if it hadn't had focus at the time of
" the call
fun! s:NERDTreeSteppedClose()
  if s:IsCurrentWindowNERDTree()
    call s:NERDTreeUnfocus()
  else
    let l:nerdtree_open = s:IsNERDTreeOpenInCurrentTab()

    if l:nerdtree_open
      silent NERDTreeClose
    endif
  endif
endfun
```

<s>I also made a [pull-request](https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs/pull/21) to the author to ask him if he wants to add theses functions upstream.</s>

**The author added my pull-request to the main repository, so with the next release, you can just call the functions directly.**

Hope it helps people.